# How to match the word in the statement

Tags: regex, robotframework

I am unable to find both the `XXXX` and the `RTP_SS_RUNNING` using `should_match_regexp` with robotframework from the below output.

```
NAME                             STATUS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAAA                             XXX_SS_RUNNING
YYYYYY                           XXX_SS_RUNNING
ZZZZ                             XXX_SS_RUNNING
AA                               XXX_SS_RUNNING
MMMMMM                           XXX_SS_RUNNING
NNNN                             XXX_SS_RUNNING
PPPPPP                           XXX_SS_RUNNING
```

Comment: No wonder you can't find it - there is no "XXXX and RTP_SS_RUNNING" in your given string. There is no "XXXX" and "RTP_SS_RUNNING" either.

Comment: Please show an actual test case (see [mcve])

Comment: sorry, i want to find "AAAA  and XXX_SS_RUNNING"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below solution :

```
*** Settings ***
Library     OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    ${str} =    Get File    val.txt
    ${match}    ${group1}   ${group2}=  
    ... Should Match Regexp ${str}  (AAAA)\\s+(.*)
    Log ${group1}
    Log ${group2}
```

[image: Output]

If you are doing the same thing and you regex is not matching, then it might be case that you are missing below point :

```
Backslash is an escape character in the test data, and possible backslashes in the pattern must thus be escaped with another backslash (e.g. \\d\\w+).
```